# Are all non-squares generators modulo some prime $p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $q\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ is not a perfect square, does there always exist an odd prime $p$ such that $q$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^\times$?  Can we find always find infinitely many such $p$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a [conjecture of Artin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots). Hooley proved the conjecture is true for all nonsquare $q > 1$ if the generalized Riemann hypothesis is true for zeta-functions of number fields. Later work by Hooley, following work by R. Murty and Gupta, established the conjecture unconditionally (i.e., with no GRH assumptions) for all *prime* $q$ with at most 2 exceptions (and nobody expects there really are any exceptions at all). For example, the conjecture is provably true for at least one of the choices $q = 2$, 3, or 5 (and surely is true for all three!) but we can't pin down a specific one of those three values for which the conjecture is definitely true. To this day the conjecture is not proved for any specific value of $q$.

Comment: In what sense it is *now* almost proved? The wikipedia page does not list any recent developments.

Comment: Heath-Brown's proof is certainly a lot more recent than the conjecture itself. Didn't mean to imply any breaking news from last week.

Comment: Right, thanks .

Comment: Alon: I edited your answer. The conjecture is proved for all but at most two *prime* values of $q$, not for all but at most two values of $q$ in general. Look at the wikipedia page again when it discusses that point.

Comment: @Alon and others: you've discussed the second of Thomas' questions, but what about the first? Is it known that for every positive non-square $q$ there's a prime $p$ for which $q$ is a primitive root?

Comment: @Gerry, that's a good point. I thought about this a little and didn't get much further than observing that you want to demand $p>2$ lest the problem become trivial.