# "Bad" primitive root $\bmod p^{2}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $m > 1$ be an integer.
Does there always exist a prime $p$ such that $m$ is a "bad primitive root $\bmod p^{2}$"?
That is, for an integer $m > 1$ can we choose a prime $p$ that satisfies the following?

1. $m \bmod p$ is a primitive root,
2. $m \bmod p^{2}$ is *not* a primitive root.

(Corrected erroneous expressions.)

Comment: Do you want $m$ to be a primitive module $p$? Unclear why you call it "Bad primitive."

Comment: It's the terminology used in  http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/6/1/42.full.pdf.

Comment: But that's not the definition given. A "bad primitive" is a primitive modulo $p$ (which means $m^n\not\equiv 1\pmod p$ for $n<p-1$) such that it is not a primitive modulo $p^2$, which is to say $m^n\equiv 1$ for some $n<p(p-1)$. That latter is equivalent to saying $m^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$.

Comment: You are not using the terminology from that link correctly. The term used there is "bad primitive *root*", and in any case it means something different from what you wrote: the first condition should not be $m^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p$, but rather that $m \bmod p$ is a primitive root. *All* $m$ not divisible by $p$ satisfy your first condition, which is a lot weaker than being a primitive root mod $p$.

Comment: In particular, if $m$ is a square, say $m=4$, $m$ can never be a primitive modulo any $p$, so it can't be a "bad primitive."

Comment: Thomas Andrews, KCd: Mea culpa. Yes I should have said "bad primitive root", and should have written "$m \bmod p$ is a primitive root".

Answer (score 2):

If $m>1$ is a perfect square, it is never true for $p>2$ that $m$ is primitive root modulo $p$, so it can't be the case that $m$ is a "bad primitive root" for any $p$.

For non-square $m>0$, it is a conjecture of Artin that $m$ must be a primitive root for infinitely many $p$, but even that is not (fully) resolved. (It is know that there can only be two prime $m$ such that $m$ is not a primitive root for any $p$.) See [this answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39437/7933) to an old question of mine.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. I understand that, since the Artin conjecture for primitive roots is not resolved, my question is not resolved either.

Comment: Well, technically, I resolved your question because it isn't true for $m$ a perfect square. But yes, barring those, the unresolved nature of Artin makes it hard to resolve your question.